# Sql query with multiple column join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am facing a problem :

table1

```
C1   C2    C3  tempId
1    4      5    ab
2    6      7    fc 
3    8      9    vb
```

table2

```
ids    val
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
6       f
7       g
8       h
9       i
```

I want to pass the value of tempId i.e. ab and want a output like

```
valofc1 valofc2 valofc3 
a          d      e
```

Please help i dont know how to achieve that.

Comment: in which RDBMS ????? is it for SQL Server or MYSQL or SQLIte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   select t2.val valofc1,t3.val valofc2,t4.val valofc3 from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2 on t1.C1 = t2.ids
   inner join table2 t3 on t1.C2 = t3.ids
   inner join table2 t4 on t1.C3 = t4.ids
   where tempId = 'ab'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32097/3)

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
select t21.val as valofc1, t22.val as valofc2, t23.val as valofc3 
from table1 as t
join table2 as t21 on t21.ids = t.C1
join table2 as t22 on t22.ids = t.C2
join table2 as t23 on t23.ids = t.C3
where t.tempId = 'ab'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table (C1 int,C2 int,C3 int,tempId varchar(50))
insert into @t values (1,4,5,'ab'),(2,6,7,'fc'),(3,8,9,'vb')
Declare @table2 table (id int,val varchar(50))
insert into @table2 values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i')
select 
(select val from @table2 where id=t.C1)valofc1 ,
(select val from @table2 where id=t.C2)valofc2,
(select val from @table2 where id=t.C3)valofc3
from @t t where tempid='ab'
```